# Setting up Django Application with Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

so I am following this tutorial on digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn

The only thing I am not doing is using the DB engine and I was just going to stick with the `SQLite3` engine as the application is only small. I'm getting to the point where I am trying to run the server wgsi file and it's showing a import filename not supported error. I'm not sure how I can get around this.

I have tried running:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn 127.0.0.0:8001
```

But it's saying Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn' and showing the help it's not showing run_gunicorn

Here's my wgsi file (took the project name out):

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxxx.settings")

from django.core.wgsi import get_wgsi_application
application = get_wgsi_application()
```

Heres the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/sanderson-holdings/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Comment: This is a very old tutorial; you should probably use the perfectly good example in [gunicorn's own documentation](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/). However, for now can you post the code you are using to start gunicorn?

Comment: I'm literally just using the `gunicorn xx.wgsi` which is in the same dir as `manage.py`  and would I need to set options to get this working?

Comment: It's saying `ImportError: No module named xx.wgsi` with xx being the project name and wgsi file name

Comment: Sorry, what's in the same dir? Do you mean you have a file name "xx.wsgi" in the same directory as manage.py? You shouldn't; you should have a file named "wsgi.py" in the same directory as your settings file, ie the one with the same name as your project. Django creates that for you.

Comment: I renamed the file to wgsi.py and ran it again and it didn't work

Comment: But that's not what I said to do. You will *already* have a file called `wsgi.py` in your xx directory, no?

Comment: Yea I run the one Django generates and it just shows `ImportError: No module named xx.settings`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues when migrating from manage.py run_gunicorn to actually using the gunicorn command. I found I had to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and also the settings in addition to the actual wsgi file.

My project structure:

- eestecnet/

  - manage.py
  - eestecnet/

    - eestecnet.wsgi
    - settings/

      - deployment.py

I run the following command from the root eestecnet folder:

```
gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=eestecnet.settings.deployment --settings eestecnet.settings.deployment eestecnet.wsgi
```

in my settings I also specify:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eestecnet.wsgi.application'
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Is the eestecnet.wsgi file the same as the wsgi.py file would be? and I am just using the default settings.py file as generated by Django and tried running your command but it's not finding the setting file

Comment: I just used `settings` and it looks like it worked because it's now saying no module named company which is one of my Django modules. How would I point this in the right direction?

Comment: In my understanding eestecnet.wsgi is the same file as /eestecnet/eestecnet/wsgi.py" because rather than being a file extension, "eestec.wsgi" is a dot delimited path from the root. If one of your modules is not being found make sure your environment is set up correctly and you have your virtualenv activated. The paths to your settings app might also be incorrect, if you usually run your project from a different root.